# Windows 8/RT delete from sqlite using linq

Tags: c#, linq, sqlite, windows-runtime

I have SQLite database in isolated storage in Windows Store App.
I use `SQLite for Windows Runtime` 
 
When i want to delete all table entry I use follow method:

```
  public static async void DeleteAllProjects()
    {
        var storageFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("myDb.sqlite");
        using (var db = new SQLiteConnection(storageFile.Path))
        {
            try
            {
                db.DeleteAll<Projects>();
            }
            catch
            (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Delete error   " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

All work like a charm. 
But when i need to delete part of entries:

```
 public static async void Delete(List<Projects> projects)
    {
        var storageFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("myDb.sqlite");
        using (var db = new SQLiteConnection(storageFile.Path))
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (var project in projects)
                {
                    var existingProject = (db.Table<Projects>().Where(
                        p => p.id == project.Id)).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (existingProject != null)
                    {
                          db.Delete<Projects>(existingProject);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch
            (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Delete error   " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

I handled exeption with

```
ex.Message = "Cannot delete Projects: it has no PK" string
```

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Define ID as the PK of Projects. How to do that depends on the ORM you are using.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth, thanks for your comment. Question was stupid, but comment was obvious, but very helpful.